# How to find out what files will be installed in the filesystem when installing a package with aptitude?

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, aptitude, apt-get

In my case I want to do `aptitude install wireless-tools` but want to know which files will be installed and where in the filesystem **before** I install the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install the 'apt-file' package:

```
apt-get install apt-file
```

you then can check contents of any package without downloading the package in advance:

```
apt-file list PACKAGENAME
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go to [packages.debian.org](http://packages.debian.org/) and search for the package you're interested in. Towards the bottom of each package's page, there's a link labeled `[list of files]` (one for each architecture) that will take you to the list of files to be installed. For example, here's the [list of files for Python](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/all/python/filelist).

Comment: That's helpful, though it provides some weird results, look at the result for gnome: http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/all/gnome/filelist I suppose there should be waaaay more filesystem changes.

Comment: Oh, yeah, this approach won't give you file lists from all the dependencies. Not sure how to get that...

Answer (score 1):

You can download the .deb package without install it

`apt-get --download-only install PACKAGENAME`

And then list the contents of the .deb package.

`dpkg --contents /var/cache/apt/archives/PACKAFILEGENAME.deb`

Answer (score 0):

There is always a question before starting the update as to whether you want to continue or not.  You could still initiate the install and just say NO at the appropriate time.